# Google PubSub: SSL error when subscribing using an AppEngine push endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I created a topic which I subscribe to using a push endpoint. The endpoint is a simple AppEngine web service. The Google PubSub documentation states that endpoints must be secured by HTTPS.

I am not receiving any traffic to the push endpoint. The AppEngine web service shows no requests. I've verified through the Google PubSub dashboard that messages are being published on the topic successfully. The dashboard shows **unreachable_ssl_error** for push subscriptions. Why is Google PubSub reporting this error?

When I try to access the SSL AppEngine endpoint via a browser I receive an SSL cert error also. Is this normal for AppEngine sites?

Comment: What does the actual URL look like? Is it a versioned URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/general#https , SSL **is** supported on App Engine, but in a somewhat peculiar way.

Specifically, and I quote...:

> Note: After April 2013 Google does not issue SSL certificates for
>   double-wildcard domains hosted at appspot.com (i.e. *.*.appspot.com).
>   If you rely on such URLs for HTTPS access to your application, change
>   any application logic to use "-dot-" instead of ".". For example, to
>   access version v1 of application myapp use
>   https://v1-dot-myapp.appspot.com.

Also look at the previous paragraph at this same URL about the need for `secure` in `app.yaml` and a link to language-specific instructions on exactly how to configure things, e.g https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Secure_URLs if you're programming in Python.